# Java helper class to dynamically create member variables and getter methods

Tags: java, getter-setter, helper

I am trying to create a helper method that will take in the names (type `String`) of the member variables (could be any number of member variables) and automatically initialize/create the member variables as well as the getter methods. So I would call something like:

```
helperClass("hello", "myName", "is", "bob")
```

and the `helperClass` would look something like this:

```
public class helperClass { 
    helperClass(String ...a) {
        for (String s: a) 
            //create member variables and getter methods dynamically
}
```

So, in the end, the caller of the function would have something like this:

```
public class helperClass { 
    private String hello
    private String myName
    private String is
    private String bob

    //getter methods below
    ...
}
```

Coming from Python so wasn't sure if this type of stuff is doable in Java.

Comment: Are you talking about generating source code, or modifying the class definition in the JVM at runtime?

Comment: Java is statically typed, how would you use this dynamically created type? What getter and member variables do you expect for `"Hello"`, `"My name"`, `"is"` **or** `"Bob"`?

Comment: @azurefrog generating member variables, I edited my question a bit for clarity

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I understand, that's why in my question I stated it'll be type `String`, so let's assume they are all type `String`

Comment: Java is statically typed, and does not have python style meta programming. You **could** use a byte code library to generate your class, and you **could** use reflection to then interact with it - **but**, that is not "easy".

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can create the getter and setter methods dynamically. 
[Tutorial for Java Dynamic POJO creation](https://blog.javaforge.net/post/31913732423/howto-create-java-pojo-at-runtime-with-javassist) . But this method will involve you creating a predefined string which contains the method declaration.

Eg : 
String s= "public void doSonething(String ... args){ // Function Body }" . 
You can then convert this string into a function at runtime. Based on your need, you can define a custom string that contains the method declaration which you need. See some examples in the above tutorial link I have attached.

Answer (score 0):

i think the answer is to use an IDE. They all have "add property" functions which will generate the declaration and appropriately named getters and setters.

Should you prefer to manually enter your properties, They all also have generate getter/setter functions which will look at the properties you have entered (work out which getters and setters are missing) and offer to create approporiately named getters and setters in bulk for the ones you've selected.

To answer your specific question, yes you can write your own class that takes a list of strings (i.e. property names) and print them out as a series of getters and setters, this is basic string concatenation:

```java
  private String generateGetter(String propName) {
     return String.format("   public String get%s()\n    return this.%s;\n  }", StringUtils.capitalize(propName), propName);
  }
```

To convert the first letter of the propName to upper case (the convention for getter and setter methods, you can do it yourself or use [apache's string utils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#capitalize-java.lang.String-).

Comment: The intent is to create a helper method for callers that are calling it with different variables

Comment: I guess I do not understand your question. The above is a helper method that generates a getter. You could replicate that to generate a getter. You can call both as much as you like. You could wrap them in a larger method that generates the "class declaration" bits. The larger method could accept a List<String> of parameters and generate attributes and getters and setters for each of them. Finally you can do whatever you like with that such as print it, write it to a file or dynamically compile it. But your question is, I think, about generating that code????

Comment: Yes, exactly. My main goal is to be able to optimize this helpermethod so that even when the caller is calling it with different parameters it will be able to generate the code for them instead of having two different classes that are tailored to each input parameter.